# What should our logo look like?

Tags: discussion

One of the [seven essential questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) "What should our logo and site design look like?"

> This one is pretty straightforward. Solicit contributions, throw out ideas, post preliminary (or finished) designs, and be supportive and respectful of other people’s ideas and creativity.
>
> We have designers on staff who will actively help come up with site designs but, if an idea stemming from the community stands out as exceptional, we are happy to use it.

We will also need to talk about promotion, but it seems appropriate to discuss a logo first. One design or idea per answer please.

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based :)))

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Comment: This icon will work well with a site layout that tries to imitate the look of an eink device, with just black and white buttons, text and so on. I definitely like it!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Comment: I like this one. Simple and clean.

Comment: I definitely prefer this one over all the others, but I got confused. When doing recherches for another question here, I found [this](http://www.filedesc.com/en/file/sbrz) site, which also uses an image that looks identical to me. Could we get in trouble for using it?

Comment: @Tim - (1) The image comes up when searching for "free icons"; (2) It's used pretty widely on the web; (3) Even if not free, this was an illustration of what the design should look like. We definitely don't need to copy/paste that specific image. I'm sure Jin is more capable than me as far as drawing a new logo based on the idea.

Comment: @DVK Okay then. I am not familiar with the processes of shaping a Stackexchange site and thought these would be proposals that may be final.

Comment: @Tim - the only final proposal is what Jin does and SE team approves as far as I know

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: KIDS!  "One design or idea per answer please."  LOL :)

Comment: @JamesJenkins - fixed

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Although it would be nice if the word Books appeared to be on the book itself (proper perspective angle).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nationalunderwriter.com/assets/images/ebook-icon-medium.png

[image]

Comment: too complex: gradient, shadow.

Answer (score 1):

Description, I will need to work up a draft image.

In the lower left hand corner is an ebook reader, slightly at an angle so you can see the screen, there is an image of an open book on the screen.

There is a whirlwind coming from/to the center of the screen.  Several books are floating around in the twister (modified vision of the tornado in the 'Wizard of Oz')  The twister stretches up to the right hand corner of the screen, with some books cut off, indacting it is much bigger than pictured.

If any book titles/authors are readable in the twister, they are classics.

Comment: What did Jin ever do to you? :)))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the stylized image of an ereader?

Comment: Can you provide an image (your own or something that can be a foundation for someone with more skills to build on?

Comment: Well, basically something similar to what DVK has already posted.

Answer (score 0):

[image]