# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion, advertising

One of the [Seven Essential Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

In one sentence describe the ebook community, from this will flow much of our advertising design.

Related question
[What should our logo look like?](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116/what-should-our-logo-look-like)

One pitch per answer please.

Answer (score 7):

Whether you read, write or publish ebooks, we have answers for your questions.

Comment: This is a Modification of ananswer suggested by @Nathan Osman.

Answer (score 3):

> Whether you read or write ebooks, we have answers for your questions.

Comment: Read, write or publish?

Answer (score 3):

## Ebooks

#### Read them, write them, make them, find them.

Instead of make, you could also use "publish".

Answer (score 2):

A place to get good answers to questions about publishing or reading e-books.

Answer (score 0):

Equestions & Eanswers on Ebooks for the Ebookish

Comment: etoo emany eeeees

Comment: @DVK you are encouraged (personally invited even) to submit something better. :)

Comment: Echallenge eaccepted

Answer (score 0):

Do you carry around your own library?

We may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Read and write questions and answers about reading and writing ebooks